# iOS 7 changed my interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I tried to compile my app for iOS 7 but when I did it, the position of all the components changed and the status bar became black. How can I avoid that ?

iOS 6 and before :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_878656Capturedcran20130913105152.png

iOS 7 :

http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_939873Capturedcran20130913105216.png

Comment: Which part of NDA does it violate?

Comment: @Pradeep Since when some NDA makes a question off topic? SO has no part in the NDA.

Comment: @Pradeep you needn't post such comments. Just don't answer the question, you can't be hurt that way. :)

Comment: I wonder how Apple managed to grow a community that guards so sharply over what they can talk about.

Answer (score 5):

There's been substantial changes to how the UI elements are actually laid out onscreen, this means that the 'dead space' from the status bar no longer exists and views get the full size of the screen. There's an iOS 7 UI transition guide on the iOS developer documentation page that covers the changes in more detail for changing the views to fit.

For the status bar check the documentation for `UIStatusBar` and `UIStatusBarStyle`, which allows you to set a black specific status bar otherwise it defaults to the iOS 7 status bar style.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with autoresizing mask properties? Try to set it from XIB. I think that will resolve your problem of wrong positioning of controls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of structure of iOS 7 & iOS 6.

iOS 6 & lower :

The main view size varies depending on bar you add

Now if we consider iPhone 5 case then

Empty Main View size : 320 & [568 - status barsize[20]] = 548

MainView + Navigation bar = 320 * [568 - status bar[20] - navigation bar[49]] = 499

iOS 7 & later :

Your total main view size would be fix  [320 * 568]

Now in your case you are using navigation bar

you just need to check if [iOS 7 ] then your subview's frame should be like this

subViewframe = current frame + [height of statusbar + height of navigation bar]

I hope you are clear.